# Block body translation for Full HTML content

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

After block creation and put HTML content in body field I can't translate this content because of:

> The string blocks:block:1:body for textgroup blocks is not allowed for
>   translation because of its text format.

If I change to plain text I can translate block but it is treated as plain text while displaying. Do I have to create another block with the same HTML content (translated) and select to display only in specific language?

Answer (score 18):

Found it, 
http://drupal.org/node/1298440#comment-5127390

> In case anyone else has trouble finding this setting, it's at
>   Configuration > Regional & Language > Multilingual Settings > Strings
>
> (admin/config/regional/i18n/strings)

Comment: Thanks! I am always looking for this tweak, and your post saves my life everytime ;-)